# Calling a controller method from a button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I see this question has been ask several times before (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738573/link-to-action-create-going-to-index-rather-than-create), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243200/how-to-call-a-controller-method-from-a-button-in-rails-4), just to name a few) but I can't get it working with my case. I am using rails 5.

I have in my `posts_controller` a method called `scrape`. It creates several object instances.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def scrape
    destroy_old_data
    @some_var = Scrape.create("something")
  end
  ...
end
```

I want to create a button in `views/posts/index.html.erb` for `scrape` method, but I can't get the button to work. I am so used to use scaffold method that I don't know how to create a custom method.

Some of the methods that I tried:

```
<%= button_to "scrape", action: "scrape"%>

<%= "scrape me", { :controller => "posts", :action => "scrape"}, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

<%= button_to "scrape", posts_scrape_path %>
```

How can I create a `scrape` button in `index.html.erb` that triggers `scrape` method? Do I need to modify my routes as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new route as well

```
post 'scrape' => 'posts#scrape', as: :scrape
```

Then you have access to `scrape_path` and `scrape_url`

```
button_to 'Scrape', scrape_path
```